# parse all text after string

Tags: python, parsing

I am parsing a value:
`Sitecore Cms`

This same value is used in a longer sentence like:
`Multiple cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities in Sitecore CMS 9.0.1 and earlier`

What i am trying to do is parse numerical value after `Sitecore CMS` so `9.0.1`

What im currently trying to accomplish this is:

```
#`Sitecore Cms`
technologytitle=str(soup.find("h1").text)

#Deserialization of Untrusted Data in the anti CSRF module in Sitecore through 9.1
vulntitle=theh4.split("CVE")[0]

vulnparsversion=str(vulntitle)
```

The problem is I try to parse

```
#['\nMultiple cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities in Sitecore CMS 9.0.1 and earlier\n\n\n\n\n']
technologyvers=re.split(str(vulnparsversion), vulnparsversion)
```

This isnt parsing `9.0.1 or earlier`

**UPDATED CODE** - putting out `None`, why?

```
        technologytitle=str(soup.find("h1").text)

        vulntitle=str(theh4.split("CVE")[0])
        vulntechversion=vulntitle.strip().split(technologytitle)[1].strip() if technologytitle in vulntitle else None

        print("technologytitle was {}".format(technologytitle))
        print("vulntitle was {}".format(vulntitle))
        print("vulntechversion was {}".format(vulntechversion))
```

its printing out:

```
technologytitle was  Sitecore Cms 
vulntitle was 
Deserialization of Untrusted Data in the anti CSRF module in Sitecore through 9.1
vulntechversion was None
```

Why is it print `None` ?

i additionally tried the following:

```
>>> techtitle="Sitecore Cms"
>>> vulntitle="Deserialization of Untrusted Data in the anti CSRF module in Sitecore through 9.1"
>>> index=vulntitle.find(techtitle)
>>> if index != -1:
...     print("it exists")
... else:
...     print("it doesnt")
it doesnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long_string = '\nMultiple cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities in Sitecore CMS 9.0.1 and earlier\n\n\n\n\n'
feature = 'Sitecore CMS'

version = long_string.strip().split(feature)[1].strip() if feature in long_string else None

print(version)
```

Result:

9.0.1 and earlier

Comment: can you see `UPDATED` above - its printing out the value as `None` ? Why is it hitting that else when clearly the values are there

Comment: Please @Crapicus

Comment: Because your search strings in each example do not appear to match the text you are searching.  from your examples: You search for 'Sitecore Cms' in a string which doesn't contain it.  And in your 'additionally' you do the same.  vulntitle doesn't contain 'Sitecore Cms' so I'm not sure why you're surprised to get 'it doesn't.  Search string must be in long string!  See in my example, Sitecore CMS short string is in the long_string.  Or did you want a different behavior?